# Merge columns to one columns and new rows in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
col1   0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
 a     NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 b     NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 c     x    y   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 a     k    NaN NaN z   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 h     NaN  x   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I want to change it into:

```
col1   col2
 a     NaN
 b     NaN
 c     x   
 c     y
 a     k
 a     z
 h     x
```

Any help please?

Comment: does order matter?

Comment: No, but just consistency of the columns, i.e {[a,NAN], [c,x],.....etc.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
df=df.set_index('col1')
df.loc[df.isnull().sum(1)==df.shape[1],0]='NaN'
df.stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).replace('NaN',np.nan).to_frame('col2').reset_index()
Out[544]: 
  col1 col2
0    a  NaN
1    b  NaN
2    c    x
3    c    y
4    a    k
5    a    z
6    h    x
```